# SignalR in React Native adding S in the event name by itself

Tags: react-native, signalr

I'm creating a SignalR Connection in react native which is getting establish successfully and listen to an event call GetPrice but when I see log it show  Warning: No client method with the name 'GetPrices' found. why SignalR adding S in the event name by it self[image]

I search my entire code for GetPrices but now result found. So why am I getting this log ?
[image]

Comment: GetPrices is coming from your Server, somewhere you are using GetPrices, SignalR isn't adding an 's' anywhere.